# Normalize Oracle query but staying in SQL Only?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I got a big Oracle query running every week.

```
Select fieldA,fieldB,fieldC, ... FROM TABLE
```

FieldC contains a number of lets say 20(+) distinct strings, while total report brings about 20 000 lines.

So I want to bring theese 20(+) strings in an own table (TABLE2) , and reference them by an ID.

So inserting a new string should reference a new id automagicly, but already known strings get referenced by their ID in TABLE2.

Is there any way to afford this in Oracle only - adding something to my now running query?

Thanks in advance,

Harry

**UPDATE**

Like in comments mentioned, my questions:

`1) Insert data in TABLE1 (and TABLE2 at a time?)`

Is that possible in Oracle?

`2) Create and populate TABLE2 with surrogate keys.`

Is that possible in Oracle? What do i have to google for?

`3) Make weekely query through both tables.`

Is that possible in Oracle? What do i have to google for?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous for me. You talk about several steps: 1) Insert data in `TABLE1` (and `TABLE2` at a time?) 2) Create and populate `TABLE2` with surrogate keys. 3) Make weekely query through both tables. You need help with what step? Please, explain.

Comment: Put some examples, maybe with that we can understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, use a trigger
2. Yes, use a sequence
3. Yes, use a dbms_job